# How to auto-refresh data and politely chart Plotly in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, plotly, yfinance

Hello how to auto refresh and auto updates so I can get realtime data in plotly chart in Django (whithout clicking on refresh button on the browser)

Here is my code:

in (views.py)

```
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import yfinance as yf

def result(request):
    stock_ticker = request.GET['num1']
    period = request.GET['num2']
    interval = request.GET['num3']
    data = yf.download(tickers=stock_ticker, period = period, interval = interval, auto_adjust = True, threads = True, proxy = None)
    data['Date'] = data.index
    def candlestick():
        figure = go.FigureWidget(data = [go.Candlestick(x=data['Date'],high=data['High'],low=data['Low'],open=data['Open'],close=data['Close'],)])
        figure.update_layout(width=1400, height=800, title=f'{stock_ticker} Historical price', plot_bgcolor="white")
        figure.update_yaxes(showline=True, linecolor='lightgray', showgrid=True, gridwidth=0.5, gridcolor='lightgray', mirror=True)
        figure.update_xaxes(showline=True, linecolor='lightgray', mirror=True, rangebreaks=[dict(bounds=["sat", "mon"]), dict(bounds=[16, 9.5], pattern="hour"),])
        figure.update_traces(visible=True, selector=dict(type='candlestick'))
        candlestick_div = plot(figure, output_type='div', config = {"displaylogo": False})
        return candlestick_div

return render(request, 'index.html', {'candlestick':candlestick()})
```

also
in (index.html)

```
{% block content %}
  <center>
     {{ candlestick | safe}}
  </center>
{% endblock %}
```